# Cannot find module './transforms/babel-plugin-convert-existence-checks-to-macros'

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've recently updated ember-cli and my app to 4.10.0, and trying to build with:

```
ember serve
```

throws the following error:

```
Cannot find module './transforms/babel-plugin-convert-existence-checks-to-macros'
```

I've looked to see what module is missing. I came up with trying to install/reinstall ember-cli-babel and that didn't work either.

The ember app is on LAMP: Raspbian Linux 11 OS, Apache 2.4.54, MariaDB 10.5.15, and PHP/Laravel 8 backend

ember-cli: 4.10.0

ember-source: 4.10.0

ember-cli-babel: 7.26.11

I don't have any special ember-cli-build configurations, here it is:

```
'use strict';
const EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
module.exports = function(defaults) {
     const app = new EmberApp(defaults, {

     });

     return app.toTree();
}
```

EDIT: ERROR STACK

```
  - name: Error
  - nodeAnnotation: [undefined]
  - nodeName: [undefined]
  - originalErrorMessage: [undefined]
  - stack: Error: Cannot find module './transforms/babel-plugin-convert-existence-checks-to-macros'
Require stack:
- /var/www/html/.../node_modules/@ember-data/private-build-infra/src/debug-macros.js
- /var/www/html/.../node_modules/@ember-data/private-build-infra/src/stripped-build-plugins.js
- /var/www/html/.../node_modules/@ember-data/private-build-infra/src/addon-build-config-for-data-package.js
- /var/www/html/.../node_modules/ember-data/index.js
- /var/www/html/.../node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/package-info-cache/package-info.js
- /var/www/html/.../node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/package-info-cache/index.js
- /var/www/html/.../node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js
- /var/www/html/.../node_modules/ember-cli/lib/utilities/get-config.js
- /var/www/html/.../node_modules/ember-cli/lib/utilities/instrumentation.js
- /var/www/html/.../node_modules/ember-cli/lib/cli/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember

    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:109:19)
    at debugMacros (/var/www/html/.../node_modules/@ember-data/private-build-infra/src/debug-macros.js:6:44)
    at module.exports (/var/www/html/.../node_modules/@ember-data/private-build-infra/src/stripped-build-plugins.js:11:48)
    at Class.buildBabelOptions (/var/www/html/.../node_modules/@ember-data/private-build-infra/src/addon-build-config-for-data-package.js:149:62)
    at Class._setupBabelOptions (/var/www/html/.../node_modules/@ember-data/private-build-infra/src/addon-build-config-for-data-package.js:168:33)
    at Class.included (/var/www/html/.../node_modules/@ember-data/private-build-infra/src/addon-build-config-for-data-package.js:184:12)
    at Class.superWrapper [as included] (/var/www/html/.../node_modules/core-object/lib/assign-properties.js:34:20)
    at /var/www/html/.../node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:497:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at Class.eachAddonInvoke (/var/www/html/.../node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:494:24)
    at Class.included (/var/www/html/.../node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:769:10)
    at Class.superWrapper [as included] (/var/www/html/.../node_modules/core-object/lib/assign-properties.js:34:20)
    at Class.included (/var/www/html/.../node_modules/@ember-data/private-build-infra/src/addon-build-config-for-data-package.js:174:28)
    at Class.superWrapper [as included] (/var/www/html/.../node_modules/core-object/lib/assign-properties.js:34:20)
    at /var/www/html/.../node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:721:15
```

Comment: can you add the stack, and the versions of `ember-cli`, `ember-source`, and `ember-cli-babel`, as well as any special babel configuration you have (`.babelrc`, or inline in `ember-cli-build.js`)?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli I've updated the post. Should have included that to begin with, sorry :/

Comment: thank you! can you add the stack trace for the error?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli absolutely

Comment: ah, so this is potentially an ember-data specific issue!

I'll tag the ember-data folks in discord and see if they're familiar with this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of googling and trying a variety of things, I was able to get my ember application to launch again. Here is what worked for me, for whatever reason.

I removed all the files inside my projects `node_modules` directory

```
sudo rm -r node_modules/*
```

and reinstalled all those packages with

```
npm install
```

After this, and I'm not sure if this really had anything to do with the resolution, I updated `npm` from `9.4.1` to `9.4.2`

```
npm install -g npm@9.4.2
```

Once all of those commands executed successfully, I ran

```
ember serve
```

and I no longer received the above error.

I hadn't thought I ever used `sudo` to install any `npm` packages, at least I try to make it a habit not to. But, it's possible I screwed up during my many butchered attempts at updating my ember app from 4.9 to 4.10.